# Toggle both <div> and <p> onclick + hide <div>

Tags: javascript, class, toggle, paragraph

I have a problem, that I presumed, should be fairly easy to solve, but regardless I still haven't managed.

At this point I have a portfolio page, where each project is displayed alongside a an "Image" tag, when this tag is clicked, a bootsrtap modal pops up and shows images. I the code there also a paragraph-tag, but at the moment that is not displaying.

What I want is that the image tag, below each project is hidden, along with a short description, upon opening the page, and so when the project title is clicked, both description and the image tag is made visible.  and when the "image" is clicked, it still has the function of opening the modal.

Here's my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".li_element").each(function(index) {
    $(this).find('p,span.PopUp').first().hide();
  });

  $("li").click(function() {
    $(this).find('p,span.PopUp').first().toggle();
    $(this).find('p,span.PopUp').first().toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("expand");
  });
});
```

```html
<li class="Project" data-modal="myModal_1">

  <span id="myBtn_1">Lirma Type</span>
  <span id="year">2019</span>

  <div class="Describtion">
    <p style="display:none;">
      Typedesign
      <span class="PopUp">Images</span>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="myModal_1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- The slideshow -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="Images/Lirma/type.jpg" alt="img" width="100%">
          </div>
        </div>
        <p>Type design</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Your code and description is not clear to me! where is the element `.li_element`?

Comment: The `.li_element`, has worked just fine up untill this point. It's at thevery beginning of my html `<li class="Project" data-modal="myModal_1">`

Comment: This is not how you can make some one understand and help you solving your issue.

Comment: okay, unfortunatly I don't know how else to explain it at this point.

Comment: If no one is able to understand your question then that is really unfortunate...